# How does Pandora know who I am after I clear My cookies?

Tags: cookies, ip

I notice that with goole/fbook etc. If I am logged in i can clear my cookies and these sites automatically log me out.  However, with Pandora. Even after i clear my cookies, it will still be able to know who i am? Is this because it knows my IP?

Comment: Probably the IP address, maybe also some Flash cookies.

Comment: @hangy It's unlikely that Pandora keeps you logged in just because you have the correct IP address, since IPs are commonly shared among different people and reassigned to new users often. The flash cookie is much more likely.

Comment: @CodeInChaos Totally true. I personally don't know Pandora, so "know who I am" did not necessarily mean "logged in" to me. :) It could also be some ad or content customization or so, which can be pretty different and could take advantage of knowing the IP address.

Comment: Ok just filling in the user name could use the IP, since its not a security but just a privacy problem.

Comment: Closed as off topic by a bunch of....

Comment: please be nice. i put it for reopening voet. i dont think this is off topic. as a user who wonders it may not be, but the background is very programming related i think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its possible but not likely. They probably have stored some data in your Adobe Flashplayer-cache.

There are several ways to identify a returning visitor:

- By IP address (not reliable for security critical purposes, can changed and faked)
- By Cookie
- By Application data (such as flashplayer cookie or other plugins data)
- By a combination of various environment variables (not really realiable but sometimes the only thing you can get)

I have also seen some sites where external sources have been loaded (images and stuff) with headers so that the users browser cached them. Then they checked whether the resourced have been requested from those external domains again.

This way they could identify a returning visitor and do something. The intention was to give him a free offer only once (because the typical users deletes cookies and changes ip adress but not cache if he/she wants some free offer again). There were also cookie and ip blocking in place.

You can control/delete your flash cookies online on adobes website. Visit this link: 
http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager07.html

Comment: @Joe How do I clear Adobe Flash Player cache?

Comment: @William http://blog.ickydime.com/2008/12/how-to-delete-flash-shared-objects.html

Also, if you're looking for a way to avoid lockouts, I would recommend last.fm. They have a free desktop app that has no time limits and no ads.

Comment: You can't simply fake an IP address. But since it can be shared between multiple computers and can be reassigned quite often, it is still not a secure way of identifying a user.

Comment: @CodeInChaos why can you not you simply fake an IP Address?

Comment: You can fake the IP on *sent* IP- and thus UDP-Packets. But to *receive* IP packets you need to be in the route to the rightful owner of that IP address. And since TCP requires a handshake you need to be able to receive packets to establish a TCP connection. So to fake an IP you need to either have access to a computer along the route, or access to BGC in order to manipulate the route itself(i.e. be a provider). And the BGC manipulation will probably detected and that provider will be in for quite a shitstorm. Short version: Your provider and users from your LAN can fake it, anybody else not.

Comment: thats perfectly correct. thanks for clarifying the circumstances about ip faking

Answer (score 1):

No, it's because Flash has an independent set of cookies.

Comment: Do you know where they are stored if I am using FireFox?

Comment: see my answer for a link

Comment: @William, for starters: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_Shared_Object#File_locations